# Распаковка файла из FAT-образа в Linux

Tags: linux, файлы, файловая-система

У меня есть файл *file.img* (образ файловой системы FAT), в нём лежит файл *target.bin*, мне нужно посчитать md5 сумму файла *target.bin*. Для этого нужно сначала достать этот файл из образа, я так понимаю. Как это сделать не монтируя образ командой mount (обязательное условие)?

Comment: Какой конкретно формат имеет файл file.img? Расширение img ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: Могу сказать, что это образ файловой системы FAT

Comment: А почему монтировать нельзя именно `mount`? Ну смонтируй чем-нибудь дргим =) Какие-то странные условия задачи. Выдумагная проблема просто

Comment: @megorit а зачем вообще монтировать, если теоретически вполне возможно вытащить файл и без монтирования? (впрочем, готовых утилит для этого я не встречал)

Comment: @andreymal, при монтировании вы работаете с файлом образа через ОС. Если нет, значит вы должы сами каким-то образом извлекать файлы. Т.е., читайте документацию по образам IMG и файловой системе FAT. Удачи =)

Comment: Попробуйте покопаться в исходниках [dosfstools](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/dosfstools.html) / Вероятно в первую очередь можно смотреть на fsck.fat

Comment: @megorit Задание препода, бессмысленное и беспощадное

Comment: Можно еще попробовать утилиту TestDisk. / [Тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206#286206) есть пример, как копировать файлы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVM/Qemu или любая подходящая виртуализация может вам помочь

Переведите сырой образ (нет в вопросе типа образа, полагаю обычный dd ) и потом смонтируйте с любым дистрибутивом в виртуалку

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
   -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci \
   -enable-kvm -m 1024 \
   -device virtio-blk,drive=sys \
   -drive if=none,file=/tmp/qemu-image-os,id=sys-drive-id \
   -device virtio-blk,drive=image \
   -drive if=none,file=/tmp/qemu-file.img,id=image-drive-id
```

Там уже сможете делать все операции с извлечением, копированием, перемещением файлов, либо в самой гостевой системе либо скопируйте на хост.

**Ссылки**

- https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/images.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276480/booting-a-raw-disk-image-in-qemu
- https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Running-Guix-in-a-VM.html